# Android: why i am not able to see the ListView if there are more then one ListView in the same activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview

In My Activity there are more then one ListView. 
See the XML Layout of it:

```
<RelativeLayout  
    android:id="@+id/taxCodeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:visibility="gone">
    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:id="@+id/taxcode_EditText" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:textSize="14sp" 
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="tax code"/>
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/android:list" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/taxcode_EditText"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- PAYE Frequency Layout start-->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<RelativeLayout  
    android:id="@+id/payeFrequencyLayout"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:visibility="gone">
    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:id="@+id/payFrequencyEditText" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:textSize="14sp" 
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="pay frequency" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/android:list" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/payFrequencyEditText"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now i am able to access the first ListView with this code:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, TAXCODE));  
getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
taxCode_EditText.setText(TAXCODE[0]);
//taxCodeFinalValue = taxCode_EditText.getText().toString();
lv1 = getListView();
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int Position,long id)
    {
        taxCode_EditText.setText(TAXCODE[Position].toString());
        //prefsEditor.commit(); 
    }
});
```

But now if i access the second ListView with the below code it is not working. I am not able to see any Second ListView.

So Whats wrong in my Code?
Why i am not able to see the Second LiStView ?
Thanks.

Edited:

After Answer i have set the second listview as like below code but still not get any listview.
code:

```
ListView payFrequencyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.payFrequencyListView);
        payFrequencyListView = getListView();
        payFrequencyListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        Adapter mySecondAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, PAY_FREQUENCY);  
        payFrequencyEditText.setText(PAY_FREQUENCY[0]);
        payFrequencyListView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) mySecondAdapter);

        payFrequencyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int Position,long id)
            {
                payFrequencyEditText.setText(PAY_FREQUENCY[Position].toString());
                //prefsEditor.commit(); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: please paste the complete xml code. in this not getting clear what is the main layout you have used

Comment: Why you want main Layout?  As there is not need of main layout.

Comment: for the result like LinearLayout/RelativeLayout then how it's give output

Comment: Forget abou the Visibility as i am managing it in to the java code and it works fine. My question is, is it possible to view the more then two list view in the same activity ? if yes then how ? or why i am not able to set both the list view ?

Comment: I am also taking about the that, and yes it is possible that you can display multiple listview in single activity

Comment: @Pratik : then how ? Any Example of it ? My xml layout for the list View is like above code.

Comment: I am not able to predict it because how would I know which was the main layout in that this layout are write. I think you didn't understand your xml file is incomplete here so copy complete file and then replace with above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setListAdapter()` and `getListView()` in a `ListViewActivity` will only work with **THE** list having "`@id/android:list`" as an id.

If you want to manage 2 listviews, you will need to set another id to the second one and
retreive it using a good old `findViewById()`, casting it to `ListView` and then setting your adapter to it using `setAdapter()`.

Layout:

```
<ListView 
        android:id="@+id/my_second_list_id" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/payFrequencyEditText"/>
```

ListViewActivity:

```
Adapter mySecondAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, TAXCODE)); 
ListView mySecondListview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_second_list_id);
mySecondListview.setAdapter(mySecondAdapter);
```

Comment: i think i am just near to solution. but still noy get the listView. Pleasee updated Question.

Answer (score 2):

add **layout_weight** property for layout's otherwise only on list view will occupy the screen.,

Answer (score 2):

You have `android:visibility="gone"` for the three RelativeLayouts. Make sure you make them visible, like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.dateSelectionLayout).setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
```

to control which one is visible at each time, or simply remove `android:visibility="gone"` to make them all visible at a time.

Comment: Thanks. but i am managing that view by coading in java. So there is no any falut of it. Anything else by Java Code ?

Comment: remove all android:visibility="gone" and see what it does

Answer (score 1):

//remove this line from your Relativelayout and check your list is displaying in your graphical layout

```
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:visibility="gone
```

your id for editText is `android:id="@+id/taxcode_EditText"`

then use as

android:layout_below="@id/taxcode_EditText"

dont use `+` for reference. if its not below your declaration.

Comment: Forget about visibility as i have set it by coading.

Comment: did you check it in your graphical layout.

Comment: its displaying fine in my graphical layout when I set visible to first relative layout. if its not showing for your mean send your whole layout.

Comment: Lets consider I have displayed the visible in the xml. And set the data threw the java code still i am not able to get it.

Comment: if you can see your edittext, then your listView is empty data is not added. set some minheight and color and see its displaying or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:visibility="visible"` or

Remove entire line it will work

Answer (score 0):

Make android android:visibility="gone" for the three RelativeLayouts.

Then in every listview i saw android:layout_height="wrap_content" instead of that use any specific height android:layout_height="330" ,

because in default listview provide scrollable view if the content of list view goes beyond the height. Then put whole layout under scrollable view.